# Where are Windows 8/8.1 file operation dialog found?

Tags: windows-8.1

Hello guys please can you tell where or in what shell are Windows 8 file operation dialogs (copy, delete, move) are held. In Win XP they were found in shell32.dll under sys32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is still in `shell32.dll`. However, it looks like the File Operations for Windows Vista and later, which is Windows 8 also, has been moved to a new Interface -- `IFileOperation` interface

> IFileOperation interface
>
> Exposes methods to copy, move, rename, create, and delete Shell items
>   as well as methods to provide progress and error dialogs. **This interface replaces the SHFileOperation** function.

And this...

> IFileOperation can only be applied in a single-threaded apartment
>   (STA) situation. It cannot be used for a multithreaded apartment (MTA)
>   situation. For MTA, you still must use SHFileOperation.
>
> A full sample that demonstrates the extension of IFileOperation is
>   included in the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK). In a default
>   installation, it can be found at %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Samples\WinUI\Shell\AppPlatform\FileOperations.
>   Requirements
>
> Minimum supported client Windows Vista [desktop apps only] Minimum
>   supported server Windows Server 2008 [desktop apps only] Header
>   Shobjidl.h IDL Shobjidl.idl DLL Shell32.dll (version 6.0.6000 or
>   later)

SourceL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is there anyway to reinitialize this interface in Windows 8.1? may be by using the Windows 8 one.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no official wrapper. However, Stephen Toub has written one in an article titled "IFileOperation in Windows Vista" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163304.aspx that can be downloaded. The article also walks you through using IFileOperation from managed code. Download link is right on top -- file titled "NetMatters2007_12.exe(160 KB)"

Comment: I'll go through it. Btw yet I can't find the file op dialog scripts in the shell32 file! Any idea?

Comment: Not sure. You should check out the sample code in my answer. It's supposed to be in the Windows SDK and if you've installed that, then the default location is %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Samples\WinUI\Shell\AppPlatform\FileOperations